# Elasticsearch postfiler cancel filter

Tags: java, filter, lucene, elasticsearch

In the following query I want to filter the query results to `size` `medium` and `color` `blue` but I want aggregations to ignore that the `color` `blue` is applied.

```
{
  "query":{
      "bool" {
          "must": {
              "query_string": {
                  "query": "foo"
              }
          },
          "should": {
              // deferred
          }
      }
  },
  "filter": {
      "term": {"size": "m"}
  },
  "aggregations": { 
     // deferred
  },
  "post_filter":{
      "term":{"color":"blue"}
  }
}
```

The problem is whenever the `post_filter` is present the *size* `filter` no longer has any effect on the query result. What am I missing?

**EDIT**: elasticsearch version 1.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter is acting as a post_filter, i.e. it gets overwritten by the subsequent post_filter.

You should either have a post_filter that covers both the size and color (if you want these excluded from the aggregation) or move the size filter into a filtered query:

```
"query": {
 "filtered": {
   "query":{
     "bool" {
        "must": {
          "query_string": {
              "query": "foo"
          }
      },
      "should": {
          // deferred
      }
    }
  },
  "filter" : {
    "term": {"size": "m"}
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of elasticsearch you are using?

If you want certain filter to be considered in aggregation it should be inside a query scope (so use filtered query), any other filter is considered out of the query scope so won't be considered for aggregation count but will affect the final output.

Change the query as below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "foo"
                        }
                    },
                    "should": {
                        //deferred
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "size": "m"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        //deferred
    },
    "post_filter": {
        "term": {
            "color": "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

This will aggregate on result of `size:m` only but final result will be on `color:blue` and `size:m`